# how can I fix timeout on scapy

Tags: python, timeout, scapy, icmp

I am currently working on a script to perform ICMP scanning, but I am facing an issue with the timeout parameter. Despite setting the timeout value to 0.01 to speed up the scan, the script always waits for 2 seconds before assuming that a host is unreachable.

I suspect that the default timeout value in the sr() function of the Scapy library is causing this unexpected behavior. Do you have any suggestions on how I can modify my script to accurately reflect the timeout value that I have set?

Thank you for your help.

```
def icmp_ping(host):
    icmp = IP(dst=destination)/ICMP()
    ans, unans = sr(icmp, timeout=0.01, verbose=False)
    return ans
```

I tried all scapy versions but it didn't work

Comment: looking at the code suggests to me that `timeout` is the time since the last packet was observed, not the time for the first packet to be observed but that is just a quick glance at the code.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test your code since I don't really recognize the functions used, but I think you can launch the function in a separate thread and use the timeout on the thread join method.

```py
from threading import Thread

t = Thread(target=icmp_ping, args=(host,))
t.start()
t.join(timeout=0.1)
```